# Django Adding Material

Tags: python, django

I am making a site to help me calculate the costs of my craft projects.

```
class Supply(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    type = ForeignKey(SupplyType, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    vendor = ForeignKey(Vendor, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    width = FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    length = FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    thickness = FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    amount = FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    cost = FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    @property
    def square_inches(self):
        try:
            return round(self.width * self.length, 2)
        except:
            return "N/A"
    @property
    def cubic_inches(self):
        try:
            return round(self.width * self.length * self.thickness, 2)
        except:
            return "N/A"
    @property
    def cost_per_square_inch(self):
        try:
            return round(self.cost / self.square_inches, 2)
        except:
            return "N/A"
    @property
    def cost_per_cubic_inch(self):
        try:
            return round(self.cost / self.cubic_inches, 2)
        except:
            return "N/A"
    @property
    def cost_per_each(self):
        try:
            return round(self.cost / self.amount, 2)
        except:
            return "N/A"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Supplies"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.vendor}-{self.name}"

class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Product(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    product_type = ForeignKey(ProductType, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I would like to be able to add different amounts of supplies to products.
For example, adding wood and glue to make a picture frame. The wood would be added as a supply item. Then to add a product, I don't know how to add wood in a certain amount to the product.
Different products will have a varying number of supplies so I do not want to

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = Charfield(max_length = 200)
    supply_1 = ForeignKey(Supply, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    supply_2 = ForeignKey(Supply, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

I would be entering something like Supply -> Wood, Amount -> 10 Cubic Inches and then have it total the cost of the wood. And then keep adding for all the supplies added to a product

Answer (score 0):

You can use [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for your usecase via [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = Charfield(max_length = 200)
    supplies = models.ManyToManyField(Supply)
```

```
supply_wood = Supply.objects.create(name='Wood', ...)
supply_glue = Supply.objects.create(name='Glue', ...)

product_frame = Product(name='Picture Frame')
product_frame.supplies.add(supply_wood, supply_glue)
product_frame.save()
```

Now, your `Picture Frame` product is mapped to those 2 supplies. Should you have additional supplies, you can just add them.

```
supply_glass = Supply.objects.create(name='Glass', ...)
product_frame.supplies.add(supply_glass)
product_frame.save()
```

To access all the supplies related to the `Picture Frame` product

```
product_frame.supplies.all()
```

Since this is a many-to-many relationship:

- A single product can be mapped to multiple supplies e.g. `Picture Frame` can be mapped to `Wood`, `Glue`, and `Glass`.
- And the other way around, a single supply can be used in multiple products e.g. `Wood` can be mapped to `Picture Frame`, `Table`, `Cabinet`, etc.

  - To access the reverse relationship e.g. to access all the products that uses the `Wood` supply:

    ```
    supply_wood.product_set.all()
    ```

Comment: Any idea how to tie that in with cost of a boardfoot of wood for example. Like if a picture frame used .5 boardfeet and one board foot of wood was $10 as put in the `Supply`. Then it would tell you it used $5 of wood

Comment: The size of the wood e.g. 0.5 boardfeet and the cost of the wood e.g. $10 seems better to be mapped on the Supply model (then you can calculate the cost as a `@property` as you have already done). That way, we only have to create a Supply with the target properties and then map them to a Product. All that a Product object would have to do is access the related Supply to see such properties.